# Scalable approach for control flow of exception manager in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

In case number of nested try-catches happen to be many, e.g. a 100, is there any other way than simply writing 100 nested try-catches in the following manner?

```
  try{ 
    ....
    } catch(exception ex1)
    try{ 
    ....
    } catch(exception ex2) {
        try{
           }
     ....
```

Comment: You should take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read the documentation on try to see how it works

Comment: admittedly the question I have asked is very bad one. I found a solution in a minute later on my own. It is un-deletable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you need to this 100 times and have to use exception for your control flow (which should be avoided if possible). You could use some wrapper, like this:

```
public class ExWrapper
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly ExWrapper _prev;

    private ExWrapper(Action action, ExWrapper prev = null)
    {
        _action = action;
        _prev = prev;
    }

    public static ExWrapper First(Action test)
    {
        return new ExWrapper(test);
    }

    public ExWrapper Then(Action test)
    {
        return new ExWrapper(test, this);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        if (_prev != null)
            try
            {
                _prev.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _action();
            }
        else
            _action();
    }
}
```

This allows you to chain actions, where the next action is only executed if the first one throws. You can use it as in the following example:

```
ExWrapper.First(() => { Console.WriteLine("First");   throw new Exception(); })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Second");  throw new Exception(); })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Third");   throw new Exception(); })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Fourth"); })
         .Execute();
```

This executes all actions or lambdas in the given order, but will only execute the following action if the first throws. The example above prints:

```
First
Second
Third
Fourth
```

If you remove the `throws` in the example:

```
ExWrapper.First(() => { Console.WriteLine("First");  })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Second"); })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Third");  })
         .Then( () => { Console.WriteLine("Fourth"); })
         .Execute();
```

Only the first action is executed, resulting in the following output:

```
First
```

Answer (score 2):

You're free to nest try/catches multiple levels deep if you want.

```
try 
{
   operation1();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   try
   {
     operation2();
   }
   catch (Exception e2)
   {
      // etc
   }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why it's a bad question, I am curious. I didn't know that you are not allowed to ask questions for absolute beginners.

Comment: I hope he didn't get downvoted for answering. It's the right answer.

Comment: @killexe such beginner questions are answered much faster by only reading the documentation of the language. Therefore the downvote "this question does not reflect **any** research effort"

Comment: @JesseCarter these questions give absolutely 0 value to the site. They should be deleted, not answered, so yes

Comment: Then flag the question but not the answers. Does it hurt your feelings that a bad question exists on that site?

Comment: If a question is bad, don't we downvote the *question*? Maybe the question will get closed or removed, and if so then it should be. But an answer should be downvoted when it's wrong, not because we don't like the question and we want to punish someone for trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just write another try-block inside the catch-block.

```
try {
  //task A
} catch(Exception ex) {
  try {
    //task B
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to move your tasks to methods that return a `bool` indicating success, and then you don't have to nest your try/catches:

```
public static bool TrySomething(string someInput)
{
    bool result = true;

    try
    {
        // do something with someInput
    }
    catch
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

public static bool TrySomethingElse(string someInput)
{
    bool result = true;

    try
    {
        // do something with someInput
    }
    catch
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then in your main code, you could do:

```
string data = "some data";

if (!TrySomething(data))
{
    TrySomethingElse(data);
}
```

Comment: This is good idea too, I wish i could accept two answer!

Answer (score 0):

Nested try-catch use a lot of resources and if they get out of hand they can significantly reduce the performance of your program. How ever, you can sequentially add catch blocks:

```
try  
{
    //code here
}catch(SomeException ex)
{
    //Display what the specific exception was
}catch(SomeOtherException ex)
{
    //Display what the specific exception was
}
```

Comment: "Significantly reduce"? Are you using a 100MHz CPU? .NET can handle throwing/catching hundreds of exceptions easily. If you don't believe me, throw an unhandled exception at a nested Task

Comment: Depends on how big your program is. Some of my own projects can have 1000-2000 lines of code in one try catch, nesting them in the way Jesse Carter or killexe answered with would reduce the performance by a "significant amount".

Comment: If you have over 20 lines in a try block then your code is most likely bad, let alone over a thousand lines

Comment: **Thanks for your input, Camilo.** My program does a very specific job. And what kind of programmer tries to put down other programmers code anyway? What kind of arbitrary number is 20 lines per try catch? This is real life programming, not from your college text book.

Comment: A one thousand line try block means there are at least a one thousand different possible exceptions. I highly doubt every line there belongs to the same try block... BTW, <20 is the standard per method

Comment: I just answered the question, I wouldn't even consider programming it that way @Bender Bending

Comment: @BenderBending I imagine most developers objection (and certainly mine) to a 1000-2000 line try catch would be that the method must be breaking the Single Responsibility Principle.